# Django Messages - Message to all / specific users

Tags: django

Is it possible to configure Django Messages in a way so that the message is shown to all and or specific users?

Comment: You could create a django model to store the message and receiver, then write a middleware to return whenever that model has data for corresponding user. But it's not authentic, I refer you to use something like Django-channel to handle the notification instead of using django messages for the purpose like this

Comment: Thanks, yes I tried channels out with daphne, but I am having problems using it with django 1.11

Comment: You could create a question so that other people can help you out.

Comment: I think you can edit this question. Just add a section below, so that other people might know what you’ve tried